# How can I remove water-based emulsion paint from paving slabs?

Tags: concrete, painting, cleaning, staining

On painting the bedrooms in our new house, we've gotten some (mainly) water-based paint on some of the paving slabs on the patio. A little of it may be oil-based gloss we used for skirting boards, but the majority is emulsion.

Is there an easy way to remove it without a lot of laborious scrubbing? I was rather hoping the rain might make it fade, but it's been a few weeks and that was clearly overly optimistic on my part ;)

Answer (score 4):

The water based paint will come off eventually with rain and normal activity on the paving slabs, but it will take a while.

The only guaranteed way is to use water and a scrubbing brush or, if you don't want to get down on your hands and knees, a stiff bristled yard brush.

Answer (score 3):

A pressure washer might do the trick.  Look upon this not as a chore of tedious magnitude, but as an opportunity to acquire more tools!

[image: Pressure Washer]

Generic image -- not an endorsement of any particular brand.

Comment: Buying no-name products can sometimes lead to inferior performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - any chemical paint stripper for latex paint.  You might also try a heat gun and scraper, and then the chemical stripper.

Just think of it the same way you would exterior latex housepaint - use the same products intended to strip that.

Answer (score 0):

If it hasn't stained the concrete a pressure washer should do the trick. I use my Karcher 1800 PSI all the time on my concrete driveway when I painted some doors on saw horses and didn't take the time to put down a tarp.......took it right off no problem and no stains however, I did it right away after painting the doors.......like the next day!